# Выбор определенной строки из запроса

Tags: php

Давно не имел дело с php, многое забыл. 
Пожалуйста напомните, как выбрать из запроса необходимую строку. 
Вот выбрал юзеров:

```
$result_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ",$db);
```

Теперь из переменной `$result_users` необходимо взять строку с id, например 39.
Какая функция php есть для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепаковать в ассоциативный массив, где его ключами сделать id пользователя.

```
$user_arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_users)){
    $user_arr[$row['user_id']] = $row;
}
// Теперь можете спокойно вытаскивать всю инфу по определенному юзверю:
print_r($user_arr[39]);
```

> **Используйте PDO!**

Comment: --> Используйте PDO!
Поясните

Comment: @Радик Камалов, почитайте статейку "[Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)"

Answer (score 0):

а лучше сразу из базы забирать нужный id 
$result_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id` = '$id' ",$db);

Comment: Не лучше. Постоянно делать запросы к БД, тоже не хорошо. Лучше один раз достать и пользоваться.